Validating Google PubSub Messages with Kafka Schema and Redirecting Invalid Messages to Kafka DLQ
I'm currently integrating Google PubSub with Kafka using the Confluent PubSub connector, which is fully managed. The goal is to leverage the existing Kafka topic schemas defined in the Confluent Schema Registry to validate messages received from Google PubSub.

Is it possible to use the Kafka topic schemas from the Confluent Schema Registry to validate messages coming from Google PubSub through the Confluent PubSub connector?
If a message fails validation, is there a way to automatically send these messages to a dedicated Kafka Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) topic?

Any insights or suggestions on configuring the Confluent PubSub connector for this would be greatly appreciated.

I think records written to/from pubsub are always byte/string type. The connector only checks the schema in/out of Kafka. Any code that's written to pubsub would need its own client logic to interact with the registry

In my case, pubsub can have messages with invalid schema. The goal is to validate messages while consuming from pubsub into Kafka and forward messages that fail validation into a separate dlq topic. I went over a ton of documentation, it is mentioned that only sink connectors support dlq topics, but maybe there is a workaround
